# How to get JFileChooser to highlight the selected file?

Tags: java, windows, swing, jfilechooser, look-and-feel

When I pop a JFileChooser with a software-selected file, that file is not highlighted among the list of files (it is, however, displayed in the "File Name: " box). The only way I can get a file to be highlighted is to mouse click on an empty space in the JFileChooser List component.

For LaF, I am using Windows.

Comment: are you using windows OS?

Comment: I've said in the question that I am using Windows

Comment: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/
this may useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my issue:

```
setSelectedFile(f);
 final JList list = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(JList.class, this, "Enabled", true);
list.requestFocus();
```